# I an getting a warning message when trying to run a code to change the units of parts of my dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, warnings, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a `dataset` from `1966/05/07` to `2002/05/07`, where I am trying to multiply values between `1966/05/07` and `1973/01/27` with `0.305` to change the units of measurement. I am using the code below but it is giving me a warning message and the code stops running in `1971/01/15`. What I am doing wrong?

```
DF <- df %>% mutate(A01 = ifelse(Date>=as.Date("1966/05/07", format="%Y/%m/%d") & Date <= as.Date("1973/01/27", format="%Y/%m/%d"), A01 * 0.305, A01))
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In ifelse(Date >= as.Date("1966/05/07", format = "%Y/%m/%d") & Date <=  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", ">=.Date") for ">="
2: In ifelse(Date >= as.Date("1966/05/07", format = "%Y/%m/%d") & Date <=  :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "<=.Date") for "<="
```

Comment: I have fixed it, I just needed to add: stringsAsFactors = FALSE in the read. csv to ensure that the date.

Comment: df <- read.csv("A01.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)